# Tax rate of bitcoin trading for non-resident alien

Tags: taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency, virtual-currency

I'm an international student holding F1 visa in the states. I find information on the IRS page which says non-resident aliens are subject to 30 percent flat rate for capital gains. Does this rate apply to gains in trading in virtual currency like on poloniex and bittrex? If so, this rather high rate would make me reconsider whether it's worth trading on poloniex using my spare money.